# How clear all cookies in Nuxt3?

Tags: cookies, nuxtjs3, google-picker

I'm currently work on a Nuxt3 app for first time.
In part of app i have a form with google picker for user's drive access.
All works but when users submit the form i revoke the token used for the picker and i still have a lot of cookies from google.
I need to clear all cookies on submit.

I'm actually a little lost on the approach to resolve this problem, so if someone have a clue it will be very helpfull for me.

I tryed to use useCookie composable from Nuxt , in goal to delete all with a loop. But it seems to not get all cookies from my app, also when they are not Http Only or secure.
No problems with created one but impossible with a large part of others send by google.

I tryed to made it in native javascript but it will be hard to include the current component in client-only and not break the others parts of logic in the component.

I check on Google docs if i can make a logout logic with my picker. But i don't have users informations like clientId when users login on their drive with the picker .

PS:It's my first post on stackOverflow so if i did something on the wrong way in my post , tell me.
Thank you by advance.

Comment: To be verified but I think that you cannot delete cookies belonging to some other domain for security reasons. Also, it just feels weird to do such a thing overall, that should be on the Google picker side to manage/discard IMO.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response @kissu. 
I'm a newbie in cookie management.
I will dig for a solution to Google picker side  and post a solution if when i found it.